# Convertir un procedimiento almacenado en SQLServer a Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-11g, plsql

Necesito pasar ese *Stored Procedure* a *Oracle*, hice la misma lógica al pasarla a *Oracle*, pero me manda error en el `OFFSET`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Produccion].[MostrarCategorias]
@NumeroPagina INT,
@RegistrosPorPagina INT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT [id_categoria] AS [ID], [codigo] AS [CÓDIGO], [nombre_categoria] AS [NOMBRE], [descripcion] AS [DESCRIPCIÓN]
FROM Produccion.Categorias
ORDER BY [NOMBRE], [ID]
OFFSET (@NumeroPagina - 1) * @RegistrosPorPagina ROWS
FETCH NEXT @RegistrosPorPagina ROWS ONLY
END;
```

Intenté esto pero me manda error en el `OFFSET` como si no reconociera ese comando.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que necesitas cambiar?

Comment: Pasar ese Stored Procedure a Oracle, traté de usar la misma logica pero el OFFSET me manda error como si no reconociera ese comando.

Answer (score 1):

Si tuvieras Oracle 12, la conversión sería mucho más sencilla.  Porque a partir de esa versión es capaz de manejar los 2 aspectos siguientes que te serían útiles:

1. Sintaxis [`OFFSET ... FETCH ...`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55636). Antes de Oracle 12, solo se puede lograr algo equivalente usando `ROWNUM` o la función ventana `ROW_NUMBER()`.
2. [Implicit Statement Results](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DRDAA/migr_tools_feat.htm#DRDAA230): Antes de Oracle 12, no se permitía que un stored procedure devolviera los resultados de una consulta así como se hace en SQL Server. Mas bien, solo se podía lograr devolviendo un *ref cursor*, que no es tan práctico en su uso.

**Código en Oracle 12**

Si puedes hacerle un upgrade a tu base de datos a la versión 12, entonces puedes escribir el stored procedure de la siguiente manera:

```
create procedure MostrarCategorias(numPagina int, registrosPorPagina int)
as
  c1 sys_refcursor;
begin
  open c1 for
    select id_categoria as "ID", codigo as "CÓDIGO", nombre_categoria as "NOMBRE", descripcion as "DESCRIPCIÓN"
      from Produccion.Categorias
     order by "NOMBRE", "ID"
    offset (numPagina - 1) * registrosPorPagina rows
    fetch next registrosPorPagina rows only;

  dbms_sql.return_result(c1);
end;
```

...que puedes ejecutar así:

```
begin
  MostrarCategorias(numPagina => 1, registrosPorPagina => 10);
end;
```

... o así:

```
execute MostrarCategorias(numPagina => 1, registrosPorPagina => 10);
```

**Código en Oracle 11**

Pero si no tienes el lujo de poder hacerle un upgrade a tu base de datos, la paginación se debe hacer usando `ROWNUM` o la función ventana `ROW_NUMBER()`, esta última siendo la opción mas sencilla.

El otro problema es que como te mencioné arriba, en Oracle 11, no hay una manera *conveniente* de devolver un resultado de consulta desde un stored procedure. Hay maneras, usando un *ref cursor* como parámetro de salida, pero son muy inconvenientes en su uso.

De estar en tu lugar, yo optaría por usar un [`PIPELINED TABLE FUNCTION`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28425/pipe_paral_tbl.htm#CHDJEGHC). Tiene la desventaja que necesitas definir 2 `TYPE` que representan los campos de los registros que vas a devolver. Pero una vez definidos los `TYPE` y la función, su uso es muy sencillo.

Por ejemplo, no conozco la estructura exacta de tu tabla `Categorias`, pero voy a asumir que `id_categoria` es numérico y que las demás son texto. Asumiendo esto, tendrías que definir los `TYPE` siguientes para poder definir la función (ajusta los tipos de los campos para reflejar tu estructura):

```
create type CategoriaRow as object (
  "ID" int,
  "CÓDIGO" varchar2(100),
  "NOMBRE" varchar2(100),
  "DESCRIPCIÓN" varchar2(100)
);

create type CategoriaTable is table of CategoriaRow;
```

Ahora puedes definir la función siguiente (nota el uso de `ROW_NUMBER()` para efectuar la paginación):

```
create function MostrarCategorias(numPagina int, registrosPorPagina int)
return CategoriaTable pipelined as
begin
  for rec in (
    select *
      from (select id_categoria, codigo, nombre_categoria, descripcion,
                   row_number() over (order by nombre_categoria, id_categoria) as rn
              from Produccion.Categorias)
     where rn > (numPagina - 1) * registrosPorPagina
       and rn <= numPagina * registrosPorPagina
     order by rn
  ) loop
    pipe row(CategoriaRow(rec.id_categoria, rec.codigo, rec.nombre_categoria, rec.descripcion));
  end loop;
end;
```

Ahora puedes ejecutar la función de forma conveniente como si estuvieras consultando una tabla normal:

```
select * 
  from table(MostrarCategorias(numPagina => 1, registrosPorPagina => 10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo uso Oracle 11g y siempre pagino mis consultas mediante **ROWNUM** y un **COUNT(*) OVER()**. En concreto para tu ejemplo sería algo así:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Produccion.MostrarCategorias (
    NumeroPagina IN NUMBER,
    RegistrosPorPagina IN NUMBER,
    consulta OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) AS
BEGIN
    OPEN consulta FOR
        SELECT k.*
        FROM (
            SELECT j.*,
                CEIL(j.total_reg / RegistrosPorPagina) AS total_pag,
                ROWNUM AS rid
            FROM (
                SELECT id_categoria AS ID, 
                    codigo AS CÓDIGO, 
                    nombre_categoria AS NOMBRE, 
                    descripcion AS DESCRIPCIÓN,
                    COUNT(*) OVER () AS total_reg
                FROM Produccion.Categorias
                ORDER BY NOMBRE,
                    ID
            ) j
        ) k
        WHERE k.rid BETWEEN RegistrosPorPagina * (NumeroPagina - 1) + 1 AND RegistrosPorPagina * NumeroPagina;
END;
```